# A question about multiplication of Dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

If $a,b\in \mathbf{Q}^+$, how to prove $\{p\ |\ p\in \mathbf{Q}, 0<p<ab\}\subset \{rs\ |\ r,s\in \mathbf{Q},\ 0<r<a,\ 0<s<b\} $?

Here is my try:

Suppose $q\in \{p\ |\ p\in \mathbf{Q}, 0<p<ab\}$. Then $q\in\mathbf{Q}$ and $0<q<ab$. So $1<\frac{ab}{q}$ and $1<\sqrt{\frac{ab}{q}}$. So, we have $q=\frac{a}{\sqrt{\frac{ab}{q}}}\frac{b}{\sqrt{\frac{ab}{q}}}$. Here, $0<\frac{a}{\sqrt{\frac{ab}{q}}}<a$ and  $0<\frac{b}{\sqrt{\frac{ab}{q}}}<b$. The problem is that $\frac{a}{\sqrt{\frac{ab}{q}}}$ and $\frac{b}{\sqrt{\frac{ab}{q}}}$ may not in $\mathbf{Q}$. As a result, I fail to prove it. Could you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *main* point is that if $a,b$ are positive rationals and $0<p<ab$ then there exists a number $b’$ which is less than $b$, such that $0<p<ab’$.
*Proof*: Pick a small enough  positive rational $\delta$ less than $b$, such that $p+a\delta<ab$ then we have $p<a(b-\delta)$ and set $b’=b-\delta$. 
 Now to prove the statement let $r=p/b’$ and $s=b’$.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is amazing!!!!! It seems that there is another method -- just use the proved lemma twice. But your method is more elegant.